# How to reinitialize other Jquery functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using [jquery.upvote.js](https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote) to add upvote/downvote functionality to the comments. I am originally initializing the vote buttons and function on `document.ready()` and it works perfectly when I load the page.

Submitting comments and displaying the newly submitted ones is done via AJAX.

The problem is when I add a new comment all the voting buttons on all the comments become unclickable. I guess the problem is that they are not being reinitialized.

Comments and Posts voting buttons in `post.blade.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.topic').upvote();
        $('.comment').upvote();

        $('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $button = $(this);
            var postId = $button.data('post-id');
            var value = $button.data('value');
            $.post('http://localhost/r2/public/votes', {postId:postId, value:value}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success')
                {
                    // Do something if you want..
                }
            }, 'json');
        });

        $('.commentvote').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $button = $(this);
            var commentId = $button.data('comment-id');
            var value = $button.data('value');
            $.post('http://localhost/r2/public/commentvotes', {commentId:commentId, value:value}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'success')
                {
                    // Do something if you want..
                }
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
```

Submitting the comments to the database in `comment.js`

```
$(document).ready(
    hide_comment_fields
);
$(document).on('focus', '.commenter-comment', show_comment_fields);

function hide_comment_fields(){
    $('.commenter-name-email').hide();
    $('.commenter-captcha').hide(); 
}
function show_comment_fields(){
    $('.commenter-name-email').show();
    $('.commenter-captcha').show();
}

// Post a Comment
function commenter_fields(){
    return [
        'commenter_parent',
        'commenter_comment',
        'commenter_post'
    ];
} 

$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){
    var form_data = {
        'per_page': $('.comments_per_page').val(),
        'commenter_parent': $('#commenter_parent').val(),
        'commenter_post': $('#commenter_post').val(),
        'commenter_comment': $('#commenter_comment').val(),
    };

    var arr = [
        'commenter_parent',
        'commenter_post',
        'commenter_comment'
    ];

    for (var i in arr, i < arr.length, i++) {
        var elem = arr[i];
        form_data[elem] = $('#' + elem).val();
    }

// console.log(form_data); // something like => Object {per_page: "some_value", commenter_parent: "some_value", commenter_user_id: "some_value", commenter_comment: "some_value"}

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post_this_comment',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(comment_done_handler);
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler);
});

function comment_done_handler(data){
    console.log(data); // data is sent from server
    $('.comment-content').append($('.reply-content .comment-fields'));
    $('.comment-list').html(data.comment_list); // put new list
    $('#captcha-image').attr('src', data.captcha); // put new captchas
    $('.comment').upvote();
    clear_input_fields();
    remove_error_messages(data);
    hide_comment_fields();
}
function clear_input_fields()
{
    $('.comment-field').val('');
}

function remove_error_messages(data){   
    var arrayelem = commenter_fields();
    for(var i=0, size = arrayelem.length; i<size; i++){
        remove_validation_styles(arrayelem[i]);
    }
}
function add_validation_styles(fieldName, responseJSON){
    var closestDiv = $('#'+fieldName).closest('div');
    closestDiv.addClass('has-error');
    closestDiv.append('<label class="control-label error-msg">'+responseJSON[fieldName]+'</label>');
}

function remove_validation_styles(fieldName){
    var closestDiv = $('#'+fieldName).closest('div');
    closestDiv.removeClass('has-error');
    closestDiv.find('.error-msg').remove();
}

function comment_fail_handler(data)
{
    remove_error_messages(data); // remove existing messages and styles
    if(data.status == 422) {
        var arrayelem = commenter_fields();
        var elem;
        for(var i=0, size = arrayelem.length; i<size; i++){
            elem = arrayelem[i];
            if(data.responseJSON[elem])
                add_validation_styles(elem, data.responseJSON);
        }
    } else {
        //open a new window note:this is a popup so it may be blocked by your browser
        var newWindow = window.open("", "new window", "width=200, height=100");

        //write the data to the document of the newWindow
        newWindow.document.write(data.responseText);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.recaptcha', function(){
    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type        : 'GET', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'recaptcha', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : [], 
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });
    request.done(recaptcha_done_handler);   
    request.fail(recaptcha_fail_handler); // fail promise callback
});
function recaptcha_done_handler(data){
    $('#captcha-image').attr('src', data.captcha);
    remove_error_messages();
}
function recaptcha_fail_handler(data){
    alert('recaptcha failed: '+data.responseText);
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.reply', function(){
    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type        : 'GET', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'reply_comment', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : [], 
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });
    var parent_id = extract_parent_id($(this).attr('class'), 'comment');
    request.done(
        function(data){
            reply_comment_done_handler(data, parent_id);
        }
    );  
    request.fail(reply_comment_fail_handler); // fail promise callback
});
function reply_comment_done_handler(data, parent_id){
    $('.reply'+parent_id).append($('.comment-fields'));
    $('.reply'+parent_id).prepend(data.cancel_reply);
    $('.commenter-parent').val(parent_id); // set parent id
}
function reply_comment_fail_handler(data){
    alert('reply comment failed');
}

function extract_parent_id(classes_attr, prefix){ // example: extract id 12 from class such as comment12

    var classes = classes_attr.split(' ');

    for(var i=0; i < classes.length; i++)
        if(classes[i].indexOf(prefix) > -1){
            var result = classes[i].substr(prefix.length);          
            return result;
        }
    return '';  // no id found, return empty string
}

$(document).on('click', 'a.cancel-reply', function(){
    $('.comment-content').append($('.comment-fields'));
    $('.cancel-reply-field').remove();
});

$(document).on('change', 'input.comments_per_page', function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('per_page', $('.comments_per_page').val());
    var request = $.ajax({ // push question data to server
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'per_page', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    });
    request.done(per_page_done_handler);
    request.fail(per_page_fail_handler); // fail promise callback   
});
function per_page_done_handler(data){
    console.log('Per page successful');
    $('.comment-list').html(data.comment_list); // put new list
}
function per_page_fail_handler(data){
    console.log('Per page failed');
}
```

For example, I have tried to use [jScroll.js](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll) to add infinite loading to the posts list, but since posts also have voting buttons, they become unclickable after loading the second page.

I have tried doing this to no avail

```
function voteClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var postId = $button.data('post-id');
    var value = $button.data('value');
    $.post('http://localhost/reddit/public/votes', {postId:postId, value:value}, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success')
        {
            // Do something if you want..
        }
    }, 'json');
}

$('.vote').on('click', 'voteClick'); // use new function here

$('.scroll').jscroll({
    autoTrigger: true,
    nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
    contentSelector: 'div.scroll',
    callback: function() {
        $('ul.pagination:visible:first').hide();
        $('.vote').on('click', voteClick); // add this to apply the event to all of your .vote elements again.
    }
});
```

Comment: what happen if you re-call .upvote()?

Comment: Include all the JS in the page you access with AJAX.

Comment: @AndrewCoder I've edited my post. @BG101 if I recall it in `comment_done_handler` in `comment.js` the voting buttons work but nothing gets submitted to the database. I'd have to reload the page for that to work.

Comment: What I mean is to also embed the JS into whatever page output you are accessing via the AJAX call.  That's the only way I can ever get JS to operate on ajax returned DOM elements.  There is probably a better way to do it... I just don't know one.

Comment: @AndrewCoder you're absolutely correct, I just tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted to an answer :)

Embed the JS into whatever page output you are accessing via the AJAX call. That's the only way I can ever get JS to operate on ajax returned DOM elements. There is probably a better way to do it... I just don't know one.